# Can one erase all content and settings from command line using sudo?

Tags: macos, mdm, secure-erase

I am planning on provisining enterprise Macs using DEP/MDM and looking for a way to allow non-admin user to initiate wiping computer.

Possible from command line using sudo? Perhaps there is another way?

Comment: By the time you've added them to sudoers, they're pretty much admin anyway.

Comment: @Tetsujin What if sudo is only allowed for a single script using sudoers and script is readonly to non-admin user?

Comment: @Tetsujin You can blame most Linux distributions for the idea that sudo owns the machine, rather than being configured properly.  This allows for clueless behaviors like `sudo su` and `sudo $SHELL`.  macOS just follows along.

Comment: @sunknudsen  Define "wiping computer" before someone can answer that.

Comment: @MarcWilson On Monterey, one can select “System Preferences / Erase All Content And Settings…” as an admin to secure-erase Mac. My understanding is that this effectively crypto-shreds file system by wiping encryption key stored in [effaceable storage](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/security/sece8608431d/web). I am setting up computers for regular non-admin users and would like to allow them to use this feature.